# Quick Cufon Question...?

Tags: css, forms, cufon

I'm using Cufon to add a Custom Font to a fair bit of content on my site.

I would like to use the Cufon on the default value of a text input field. But it isnt working, Its just loading the default font on the page. Is there any way I can do this?

Example of this is [here](http://apili.net/code/cufon/)

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using cufon. Cufon works by changing your markup and inputs do not contain markup. You'd have better luck with @font-face (try http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to do this.

If you insist on using cufon, you could display a span with the cufon'd text over the input and on click hide the span and set focus to the input.

Comment: Thanks for that @VirusZ I had my suspicions that you couldn't do that. I'll just leave it default for now. Thanks for the tips on @font-face